Как по координатам прямоугольника получить координаты описанного овала?
есть к примеру прямоугольник, как  описать вокруг него овал?Есть ли какая-нибудь библиотека которая имеет методы получения таких координат в формате (x1, y1,x2, y2)?
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=250, height=170, bg='white')
canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
rect = canvas.create_rectangle(100, 30, 50, 100)
root.mainloop()

результат хотел и круг и эллипс через метод create_oval, если эллипс что б его границы(или дуги?) были максимально близки к граням  прямоугольника

Что имеется в виду под овалом? Если эллипс, то нужно ещё задать ограничение, например, на соотношение полуосей.

И какие координаты требуется получить?

@u_mulder в tkinter фигуры задаются координатами противоположных углов ограничивающего прямоугольника.

Ну так я и понимаю что прямоугольник можно задать двумя парами координат. А эллипс чем?

Но в целом да, через 4 угла прямоугольника можно кучу разных эллипсов провести, можно в том числе круг.

@u_mulder чтобы его нарисовать через метод create_oval.

О как, ну да, так более понятно) Тут видимо надо искать прямоугольник, в который будет вписан этот эллипс, он-то точно будет один.

подправил желаемый результат

Возьмём простой и логичный случай - соотношение осей эллипса соответствует соотношению сторон прямоугольника (тогда описанный эллипс подобен вписанному).
Если взять квадрат со стороной h, то описанная вокруг окружность имеет радиус h/sqrt(2). Если теперь растянуть квадрат до прямоугольника с шириной w, то из окружности получится эллипс с полуосями (w/sqrt(2), h/sqrt(2)) - это и есть размер прямоугольного окна, задающего эллипс в create_oval
(x1, y1,x2, y2) =>
cx = (x2+x1)/2
cy = (y2+y1)/2
w = x2-x1
h = y2-y1
create_oval(cx - w/1.414, cy - h/1.414, cx + w/1.414, cy + h/1.414)



@ВадимМотеюнас Ну что, разобрались?

да спасибо,  есть какой нибудь удобоваримый ресурс где есть эти формулы, теория?В идеале бы библиотеку которая умеет это все считать сама

Ну про эллипс можно хоть в википедии почитать, но здесь практически ничего не нужно из теории, математика простая. А про библиотеки не знаю.  Собственно, пять строчек, приведённые выше, всю работу выполняют.

погорячился я сказав что все понял, не ясно мне что такое cx,cy  что они вычисляют?

Это координаты центра прямоугольника и эллипса, вспомогательные величины
